# Android menu option overlapping dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have created two dialog and I am shoing those dialog in menu otions. But when I am clicking on search meu option it is overlapping with sync menu option. I have tried everything but no solution. can anybody tell me the solution.

My code:

```
    @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
 {
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}       
   @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {    
        // Handle item selection
        case R.id.Synch:
            showDialog(SYNC_ALERT);     
            return true;
        case R.id.searchid:
            showDialog(SEARCH_ALERT);   
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    switch (id) 
    {
        case SEARCH_ALERT:
        // Create out AlterDialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Search");
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View searchView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_dialog, null);
        builder.setView(searchView);
        Searchtxt = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_text);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Search", new searchOkOnClickListener());
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new searchCancelOnClickListener());
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

        case SYNC_ALERT:
        AlertDialog.Builder alertbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertbuilder.setMessage("Synchronization");
        alertbuilder.setCancelable(true);
        LayoutInflater buildinflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View SyncView= buildinflater.inflate(R.layout.sync_layout, null);
        alertbuilder.setView(SyncView);
        defaultchkbox = (CheckBox)SyncView.findViewById(R.id.defaultchkbox);
        after15mint = (CheckBox)SyncView.findViewById(R.id.after15mint);
        afternmint = (CheckBox)SyncView.findViewById(R.id.afternmint);
        alertbuilder.setPositiveButton("Save Changes", new syncOkClickListener());
        alertbuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new syncCancelClickListener());
        AlertDialog alertdialog = alertbuilder.create();
        alertdialog.show();
    }
            return super.onCreateDialog(id);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure about your question, so I assume that you get the syn dialog when clicking on search menu option. If that is the case, you should put break between each case of the switch.

```
switch (id) 
{
    case SEARCH_ALERT:
    ..................
    break;

    case SYNC_ALERT:
    .................

}
```